# Integration over a Surface without using Partition of Unity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds, integration, riemann-surfaces

Suppose we are given a compact Riemann surface $M$, an open cover $\mathscr{U}=\{U_1,U_2,\dots\}$ of $M$, charts $\{(U_1,\phi_1),(U_2,\phi_2),\dots\}$, holomorphic coordinates, $\phi_m:p\in U_m\mapsto z_m$, holomorphic transition functions $z_m=f_{mn}(z_n)$ on patch overlaps $U_m\cap U_n$ (with appropriate cocycle relations, $f_{mn}\circ f_{n\ell}\circ f_{\ell m}=1$ on triple overlaps $U_m\cap U_n\cap U_\ell$), and a globally defined top form, $\omega=\omega(z,\bar{z})dz\wedge d\bar{z}$.

I want to integrate $\omega$ over $M$,
$$
I= \int_M\omega,
$$
using the above data (without using a partition of unity), and I'm wondering whether my reasoning is correct. In particular, suppose we construct non-overlapping sets $\{V_1,V_2,\dots\}$ such as those shown in the figure:
[image]
**My question** is whether I can compute $I$ via a sum of integrals over the $\{V_1,V_2,\dots\}$ (to guarantee no overcounting) without using a partition of unity; i.e., is it true that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I &= \sum_m\int_{V_m}\omega\\
&=\sum_m\int_{V_m}\omega_m(z_m,\bar{z}_m)dz_m\wedge d\bar{z}_m
\end{aligned}
\qquad\qquad\qquad(*)
\end{equation}
In the examples I have considered (such as $\omega=\frac{i}{2\pi}\mathcal{R}_{z\bar{z}}dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ the curvature tensor or $\omega=ig_{z\bar{z}}dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ the volume form) this gives the right answer (e.g. the Euler characteristic in the first example and area in the second) but I would like to know if it is true in general. Thanks!

**Update I:** It should presumably be possible to derive (*) using a partition of unity subordinate to $\mathscr{U}$. If so, how might one derive the last equality in:
$$
I=\int_M\omega=\int_{M} \omega\big(\sum_m\lambda_m\big)=\sum_m\int_{U_m}\omega\lambda_m = \sum_m\int_{V_m}\omega
$$

**Update II:** This question now has a clear and explicit answer at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3137362/531892)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: You can indeed do such a computation. Any top form defines a measure on the surface, making is a measure space, and the boundaries of the $V_m$s have measure zero.

Comment: Isn't this a special case of a partition of unity, namely the characteristic functions of the $V_n$?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate numerically over a specific Riemann surface, or are you doing something more theoretical?  I have some possibly relevant experience for numerical calculations.

Comment: thats great, thanks for your comments. @AchimKrause: I have not heard of this terminology (namely 'characteristic functions of the $V_m$') and can't find it in the index of any of my differential geometry and related texts.  I would like to be able to consider this as a special case of a partition of unity if this is what it is.  Can you point to a reference?

Comment: @NeilStrickland: I don't have numerics in mind, but if you have some relevant comments please let me know.  In my case of interest $\omega$ is the pairing of a vector-valued $(0,1)$-form, $\mu$, with a holomorphic quadratic differential, $\varphi$, and the motivation for doing the above is that I only know the explicit expression for $\mu$ in local domains diffeomorphic to discs.

Comment: By the characteristic function of $V_n$ I just mean the function that is constantly 1 on $V_n$ and 0 outside of it. That's a partition of 1 if the $V_n$ cover the whole space and don't overlap.